# CSS seems to be not working in a subdomain?

Tags: css

I developed a website using code igniter, styled it with CSS, locally it works fine but online it looks like css is not loaded it picks up the old css style. I checked the link but it's correct. What gives?

Comment: If you're using Firefox, I imagine it is a CORS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information (such as seeing the site in question), I can't give you a direct answer, but I can give you some pointers.

My suggestion is to use a tool like Firebug (in Firefox) or Chrome's Developer Tools, etc. These tools allow you to see full details of all requests being made by the browser.

(the exact instructions will differ according to the tool you're using, so I'll assume Firebug for simplicity).

Open your page in the browser, with Firebug open, and look at Firebug's "Net" tab (And make sure that the option below the tab is set to "All"). This will list all requests that are made by the browser.

The key thing for you is to look for any 404 errors. Since you say your CSS isn't working, it's a pretty good bet that your stylesheets are failing to load. The 404 errors listed in Firebug will show you why they're failing to load.

If you hover over the filenames, Firebug will expand it to show you the full URL that it attempted to load. This will almost certainly show you that you've got something wrong in your configuration, and it's trying to load the stylesheets (and possibly other files too) from the wrong location. This should show you what's going wrong and give you a enough clues to be able to work out how to fix it.

Hope this helps you solve the problem.